# Updating values in through model using Sequelize

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I currently have two models (user and group) in a many-to-many relationship through the model, userInGroup.

**I now need to update the through model, more exactly the userInGroup.lastChecked parameter. How do I best do that when I have already queried and retrieved the user and/or group model?**

Something like this?

```
models.user.findOne(
    {
        where: {id:userId},
        include: [{model: models.Group, where: {id:groupID}}]
    }
).then(
    function(user) {
        ???? user.Groups.userInGroup.lastChecked = new Date(); ?????
        ...
    }
);
```

Or can I only do it through a query of userInGroup directly? (This seems like a poor choice in terms of performance as I need to query the database again, since I have just queried the exact same relationship to get the user and the group)

```
models.userInGroup.findOne(
    {where: {userId:userId, groupId:groupId}}
).then(
    function(connection) {
        connection.lastChecked = new Date();
        ...
    }
);
```

Thanks!